# Cybersource Reauthorization (authorization expiry & renewal)

Tags: e-commerce, payment-gateway, cybersource

TLDR: How does one renew a Cybersource auth which has expired (leveraging an existing payment transaction)?

### Scenario:

1. Payment is tokenized & an auth is created via cybersource
2. Wait 10 days (suppose this is an order & you have to make the items)
3. Request Capture (items ready to ship)
4. /capture responds with a 400 + MISSING_AUTH (believe an expired auth will do this)

What do you do now?

[Cybersource Reauthorization](https://developer.cybersource.com/api/soap-developer-guides/dita-payments/MITs/MIT_usecases/MIT_reauthorization.html) seems to require the card number based on testing (although that page does not reference it).

How I tested this:

1. Execute [Payment Creation with Authorization](https://developer.cybersource.com/api-reference-assets/index.html#payments_payments_process-a-payment)
2. Attempt [Cybersource Reauthorization](https://developer.cybersource.com/api/soap-developer-guides/dita-payments/MITs/MIT_usecases/MIT_reauthorization.html) leveraging the id from above

Comment: Any luck with this?  I am also stumped.  The docs seem to indicate it is possible.

Comment: Yes & no? You need to use a paymentInstrument in order to do it. Which you would create at acceptance by tokenizing the card (which I believe is a charged feature for Cybersource).
 "paymentInstrument": {
      "id": "xxxxx"
    }